# Is a property an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand objects and the dot notation property accessor:

is `document.createElement('pre')` the same as saying `createElement()` is a property of `document` because I am using the dot notation property acccessor? Would that mean properties are also objects?

In the example above, is the dot operator performing a different function than accessing a property, just like the `+` operator can perform both addition and concatenation? It looks like `createElement` is a property of `document`.

I am unable to answer this after reading the following sources:
[MDN Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)
[Dot Notation vs Bracket Notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)

Comment: the dot is used to access `properties` and `methods` (functions) of an object. if you're starting i recommend http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is document.createElement('pre') the same as saying createElement() is a property of document because I am using the dot notation property acccessor?

Yes.

> Would that mean properties are also objects?

They can be. Properties have a value, which can be a primitive (number, string, undefined, etc.) or a reference to an object (Array, Object, DOM Element, Function). Where a property references a Function or callable object, it's called a *method* of the object that has the property.

So in the above, *createElement* is a method of the *document* object.

> In the example above, is the dot operator performing a different function than accessing a property, just like the + operator can perform both addition and concatenation?

No. Dot property accessors are a convenience and can only be used where the property name is a valid identifier, e.g. you must use square bracket notation for a property with a name of *foo-bar* since a name with a hyphen is not a valid identifier, but can be used as a property name:

```
var obj = {'foo-bar': 'fum'};
```

Square bracket notation also allows the use of variables for property names:

```
var propName = 'foo-bar';
var obj = {};
obj[propName] = 'fum';
console.log(obj['foo-bar']); // 'fum'
```

> It looks like createElement is a property of document.

It is, so that's a good thing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `document` object has a property named `createElement` whose value is a function.

The property is not itself an object, but in this case it holds a reference to an object (specifically a function).

Note that you could also use `document["createElement"]` instead of `document.createElement`, which may make it more obvious that we're talking about a property of `document`.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is an object. `createElement` is a method of this object.
in JS if it ends in (...) it is a method/function, or a construct, like `if(...)`

Since in JS methods/functions are objects too, so yes, u can say createElement is a property which points to an object.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript object "properties" can be:

- Primitive types (String, Number)
- Functions
- Objects
- Arrays

When a property of an object is a function, it is called a METHOD of that object.

In your example, you "could" write a dot notation such as:
`document.createElement;` (this would return the METHOD itself).

When you type:
`document.createElement('tagName');` it invokes the document's createElement METHOD with  a parameter value of "tagName".

Basically, in both cases you are "accessing the object's property", but in the second case (with parenthesis and parameter) you're also INVOKING that property.

**Now to answer your specific questions:**

1. Yes, object properties can also be objects.
2. No, the dot operator is ONLY accessing that object's METHOD (createElement is a METHOD of the document OBJECT).
3. Yes, createElement is a property of the document object, but that property being a function we call it a METHOD of the document object.

I know i've repeated myself a lot, but I tried to sum up the essential of your question.
If you need more info, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting caught up in semantics.  Honestly, I started writing a near novel as an answer, but decided I will make it more concise.

In JavaScript, don't think about `objects` as being composed of `properties` and `methods`.  It will just confuse you, because it is harder to define the difference in JS.

Think of `objects` as being composed of `key-value pairs`.  A `key` is just a shorthand name for a `value`.  A `value` can be:

- A number
- A boolean value
- A string
- An array
- A function
- Another object
- An expression

AKA, values can be just about *anything*.  That is why it can get really, really confusing when you start labeling `properties` and `methods` of javascript objects.  Trust me, just consider everything a `key` or a `value`, and you will save yourself a headache.

---

To answer your original question:

A `property` *can* be an `object`, but doesn't have to.

Semantic breakdown:

- The `document` object has a `property` called `createElement`.
- `createElement`'s value is a `function`, therefore `createElement` is a `method`.
- In JavaScript, a `function` is actually a special type of `object`.

So when we put it all together, `createElement` is a `property`, `method`, *and* an `object`.  See why `key-value pairs` are easier to conceptualize? ;)